# Не работает соединение между PHP и MySQL database. Как можно правильно написать код?

Tags: html, mysql, веб-программирование

В главной странице html есть форма для пользователей чтобы войти, в форме для логина нужно ввести почту и пароль пользователя. В Registration.php коде берут введенную почту и пароль и сверяют ее со существующей в базе данных. A config.php коде открывается соединение между  PHP и MySQL database. Где есть ошибка но не могу найти ее. Буду благодарен если поможете.

```html
<form action="Registration.php" method="POST">
<div class="row">
          <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
          <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
          <input type="submit" value="Login">
        </div>
      </form>
```

Registration.php

```html
<?php
include 'config.php';

session_start();

error_reporting(0);

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
     $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
 if ($row['email'] == $email && $row['password'] == $password)
 {
     echo "<script>alert('Login success! Welcome.$row['$username']')</script>;
 } else
 {
     echo "<script>alert('Failed to login')</script>;
 }
}
?>
```

config.php

```html
<?php 

$server = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$database = "*********";

$conn = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass, $database);

if (!$conn) {
    die("<script>alert('Connection Failed.')</script>");
}

?>
```

Comment: во-первых https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701145/191482  во-вторых https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701146/191482

Answer (score 0):

> if (isset($_POST['submit']))

Это не так работает. Submit - это тип инпута, который заставляет форму работать, естественно твой код не работает, ведь условие не выполняется. Замени на isset($_POST['Email'].

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо что помогли. Я поменял как вы сказали но ничего не изменилось. После нажатия кнопки submit в странице открывается код Registration.php но никак не js alerts. Все папки и материалы находятсы в папке  htdocs и есть тестовые данные для таблицы в базе данных но все еще код как то не работает

Comment: можете подсказать что делать дальше?